# Unable to open htdocs soft link to shared folder

Tags: apache, ubuntu, windows-7, virtualbox, symlink

After sharing windows folder using Virtual Box Share, it is accessible on Ubuntu machine. Also I am able to successfully create symlink to the folder inside Ubuntu Guest and browse the folder.

However the symlink existing as `"test"` inside htdocs is not accessible over localhost. `localhost/test` gives following error -

```
Access forbidden - dont have read / write permission
```

I have tried adding following to httpd-vhosts file -

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /opt/lampp/htdocs/test
    <Directory>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

With that also added .htaccess to test folder with following data -

```
Option Indexes FollowSymLinks
```

It still does not work and gives same Access denied error. What should be setting here since I am not using samba here and instead trying to have dev env in windows shared folder mounted to htdocs folder in apache in ubuntu

VBox - 5.*
Ubuntu - 14.04
Windows - 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following instructions from here it worked -

### [Virtual Box Shared folders](http://jimmybonney.com/articles/configure_virtualbox_shared_folder_apache_virtual_host/)

steps -

```
1. stop automount from Virtual Box 
2. add www-data to vboxsf group - sudo usermod -aG vboxsf www-data
3. add to /etc/fstab, separated by 1 tab each - project /media/sf_project   vboxsf  rw,uid=33,gid=33    0   0
4. add vboxsf to /etc/modules and restart vm
```

I am not using any vhost setttings with apache